# Eden Php - Smtp, Custom Header - How to change 'From'-Field to custom Sender-Email-Address

Tags: smtp, email-headers, eden

This is about http://eden.openovate.com/api/eden/mail/smtp.php

```
public function send(array $headers = array())

Sends an email

Arguments

array custom headers

Returns array headers
```

I understand that i have to provide an array of headers with this method to overwrite the default from header (equals by default to smtp server account address) to the "real sender" address (provided by the user filling the mail form)

*The problem is:* I cant find any documentation how to use it.

*The question is:* What is the correct way to provide this header.

(Please provide a "working code sample" of send-method call with parameter)

Thank you ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
send( array( 'From' => 'sender@address.com' ) )
```

"D'oh!".. so easy :D .. but Eden definitly missing documentation here